# How to dump (backup) several tables (collection) and recover from MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I'm new in MongoDB and my english is too bad - so, i can't understand mongodb documentation.

I have to dump (backup) several tables (collection) from MongoDB base - how I can do it?
Which utility I have to use for recover collections from backup?

Thank you for your attention for my question!

Comment: Use `mongodump` and `mongorestore`.

Comment: You should leave that to [an administrator](https://dba.stackexchange.com) anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your mongod server. Assuming that your mongod server is running on localhost and port 27017. Now open a command prompt and go to bin directory of your mongodb instance and type the command:

```
mongodump
```

This command will back all data of the server to directory /bin/dump/

To backup only specific collection, use:

```
mongodump --collection YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME --db YOUR_DB_NAME
```

On a good-bye note, to restore/recover data use command:

```
mongorestore
```